# Calculation On Large File Data

Tags: algorithms, performance

I have a task where I need to read a big data file and process the data in it. Every row in the file looks like this:

```
CustomerId   ItemId   Amount   Price
```

I need to calculate the total cost for the customer, but first I need to determine the most expensive item purchased. "Most expensive" means the item with the highest total price **sum** (per customer). I then have to subtract the most expensive item from the total cost.

My idea is to first make this table:

```
CustomerId   ItemId   Total_Cost
```

Next, I sort the table, find the highest cost, and store this in a variable.

Then I make this table:

```
CustomerId   Total_Cost
```

Then I subtract the highest cost from each row.

But I feel that this is a brute force approach, and I'd like to get advice on a more clever and efficient way to do this.

**My Algorithm**

```
Make Map with CustomerId key, i.e. Map[CustId, TotalCost] - calling this M1

Make another Map, i.e. Map[(CustId, ItemId), SubTotalCost] - calling this M2

// Open file and process line by line
for each line in file
  M1(CustomerId) = running_total_cost
  M2((CustomerId, ItemId) = running_subtotal_cost

// When finished processing the file
for each entery in M1
  get highest subtotal in M2
  substracting highest total in M2 from M1's running_total_cost
```

Comment: Do you literally want to find the most expensive item, or do you want to find the item where "Total amount  of purchaes " x Price is maximized?

Comment: No sir. I wanting to produce table at end with all customers and their total cost of purchases minus the most expensive item they purchased because promotioning is applied

Comment: Say a customer bought 5 apples of price 2$, and 3 bananas of price 3$, what counts as the most expensive item: the apples (since they have a total cost of 10$ vs. 9$), or the bananas (since they have a single cost of 3$ vs 2$)?

Comment: Apples will be most expensive and so this needing to be substracting from total cost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My idea is first I make this table:
>
> ```
> CustomerId  ItemId Total_Cost
> ```

That's ok, there is no way around this, you will need to determine the total price sum per item and per customer first before you can start picking the maximum.

> Then I sort the table and find highest cost

For finding the maximum value in a set of numbers, you don't need to **sort** the numbers first, that is quite inefficient. Instead, implement something along the lines of

```
 for each val in "set of numbers" do:
    current_max = Max(val,current_max))
```

Comment: Yes, this my thinking as well. But this meaning that I writing my own algorithm (which I can doing). My first thinking was to use big data library like Apache Spark, Apache Storm but I not like that because I do not knowing what they are doing inside. Makes me uncomfortable. Also I think with this solution I know exactly memory consumption but I not knowing that accurately with these libraries

Comment: @Mojo: so your real problem is, you don't how if those Apache libs provide an aggregate function for finding the maximums? Then I recommend you ask a question about exactly this at stackoverflow, name the lib, post the code you already have and describe where your problem is. Besides this, a "maximum finding algorithm" is not rocket science, that's beginners stuff.

Comment: I have choice - I not have to use Appache libraries. I can make my own algorithm and I will do this first

Comment: Then I will comparing with implementation with those libraries

Comment: I will post my algorithm soon sir

Comment: Please see my algotrithm. I update my post. Is it expensive?

Comment: @Mojo: as I already wrote in my answer: it depends on what you do in the step *"get highest subtotal in M2"*. If you solve this by sorting, then it is not efficient. If you solve this by linear maximum finding, then it looks fine to me. Note this site is not a discussion board, please don't use the "edit" system for adding new questions to an existing question. You latest edit is borderline on this, one could interpret it as a clarification, so it may be ok this time, but please don't go this route any further.